# Parsing JSON, array within an array (Android)

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse weather information from a http://www.worldweatheronline.com JSON feed. This is the format that it comes in:

```
{ "data" : { "current_condition" : [ { "cloudcover" : "75",
        "humidity" : "100",
        "observation_time" : "10:01 PM",
        "precipMM" : "0.0",
        "pressure" : "1015",
        "temp_C" : "3",
        "temp_F" : "37",
        "visibility" : "4",
        "weatherCode" : "143",
        "weatherDesc" : [ { "value" : "Mist" } ],
        "weatherIconUrl" : [ { "value" : "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0006_mist.png" } ],
        "winddir16Point" : "N",
        "winddirDegree" : "360",
        "windspeedKmph" : "11",
        "windspeedMiles" : "7"
      } ],
```

So there is the `current_condition JSONArray`, which I have managed to obtain values from. But then how do I read the values from the inner arrays `weatherDesc` or `weatherIconUrl`?

Here is my code for reading `precipMM`, `pressure`, `temp_C`, etc:

```
String precipMM = null;
    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        JSONArray current_condition = data.getJSONArray("current_condition");

        for(int i = 0; i < current_condition.length(); i++) {
            precipMM = current_condition.getJSONObject(i).getString("precipMM");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hey Matt, were you able to get this working without using Jackson library. I am stuck in similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
current_condition.getJSONArray()
```

As also with json parsing I would suggest looking at this library
http://jackson.codehaus.org/

**EDIT** After you comment

The code you posted could be improved a lot. You are iterating through the array for each value. You can do the same thing with the array. Just call .getJsonArray(), instead of .getJsonObject(). However this means your code is throwing an error for each of the other values. I would again recommend the Jackson library

Comment: I tried this, but it requires an int value, it doesn't take the "weatherDesc" string. So I used 9 as an int but that is out of range.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help, I'm new to JSON and I'm finding it very confusing. I'll play around a little and then check out the Jackson library.

Comment: I found it tricky at first. It's pretty simple once you get used to it. Essentially with jackson library you make the Java object and annotate the variables with the values you want to pull from the jsonobject. No messing about and it's quick

Answer (score 2):

`weatherDesc` and `weatherIconUrl` are provided as array, so you can access by item i.e. inside a for loop.

Just use same command as you do it for `current_condition`